# Append block of code after each match maintaining tab/spacing

Tags: notepad++

I am editing JSON dialog and have several similar dialog structures for each NPC in my RPG. I want to add new objects/arrays to my JSON structure, but don't want to edit each section by 1st ctrl+f'ing the section I'd like to append to (in this case "gather"), then manually appending more items to the end.

**Summary: I am trying to:**

- Append block of code after each match... in this case after "gather"
- Maintain the left tab/spacing within Notepad++

I've tried ctrl+h to find+replace, but this doesn't maintain spacing, and has a limit on the amount of text you can alter.

For example, "gather" object appears 30+ times in all of my JSON dialog:

```
            "gather" : 
            {

            },
```

I need to append the following after "gather":

```
            "chooseItem" :
            [

            ],
            "otherTask" : 
            [

            ],
            "playerMessage" :
            [

            ]
```

Such that it looks like this:

```
            "gather" : 
            {

            }, 
            "chooseItem" :
            [

            ],
            "otherTask" : 
            [

            ],
            "playerMessage" :
            [

            ]
```

How is this done in Notepad++?

Comment: With the extended syntax you can search/replace linefeeds etc. That should keep spacing as you want. But why would spacing matter for a machine readable data format?

Comment: Because I want to maintain a format/spacing that's easy for me to read and continue editing

Answer (score 0):

In **SynWrite** app: you can write macro, which

- finds next "gather"
- moves caret to first "{"
- calls `Ctrl+[` to jump to closing "}"
- pastes block after "}"

Run macro via Macro dialog, "Till end of file".